# How to install git repository on Bluehost

Tags: git, apache, ssh, bluehost

I've tried pretty much anything I could find on Google, if you enter: bluehost git repository all of the results on first page and some on second, I've tried. Also I've tried this very useful tutorial but not to much help, [8 ways to share your git repository](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/) So far this is what I got. When using HTTP method I can clone/fetch/pull repository to my computer but I can't push. It requires changes to be made to httpd.conf which is not possible on Bluehost. With CGI(http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-to-git-over-http) method in conjunction with HTTP I always get 500 server error. And when using SSH since I do have access to SSH shell I get "The remote end hung up unexpectedly". Most of the tutorials found on Google are at least 6 months old, for example this(http://www.calzzani.com/blog/?p=92) one offers a very good solution, but

> I was messing around with my .bashrc file all morning before finding out that bluehost no longer allows remote paths to be accessed via non-interactive logins. If only I had discovered this 4 hours sooner!

I wasted more than 4 hours trying solutions out, can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

It seems bluehost offer their own support topic for git installs now

See [VPS or Dedicated Hosting - Installing Git](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2383)

Answer (score -1):

You need to run:

```
yum install git --disableexcludes=main --skip-broken
```